# Obtener parte de expresión regular en golang como en python

Tags: python, go

Estoy aprendiendo a usar expresiones regulares en golang. Mi pregunta es: ¿cómo puedo hacer para devolver cierta parte de la expresión regular en golang como en python? Ejemplo, si yo tengo la frase *"Texto de prueba"*, y solo quiero obtener la palabra prueba, en python puedo hacer esto:

```
import re

result = re.match("Texto de (p.*)", "Texto de prueba")

print(result[1])
```

Y eso da como da como resultado la palabra *"prueba"*; ¿cómo puedo hacer eso en golang? Ya que si yo intento hacer lo mismo en golang, con este código:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    re := regexp.MustCompile("Texto de (p.*)")

    fmt.Println(re.FindString("Texto de prueba"))
}
```

obtengo como resultado *"Texto de prueba"*, no la palabra que busco.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### **TL;DR**:

> Se sugiere utilizar la función `FindStringSubmatch`.

Vayamos por partes.

##### Entendiendo lo hecho en Python

Si se busca qué retorna `.match()`, la [documentación de Python](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/re.html#re.match) dice (énfasis mío):

> `re.match(pattern, string, flags=0)`
> Si cero o más caracteres al principio de la string («cadena») coinciden con el pattern («patrón») de la expresión regular, retorna un **objeto match** correspondiente. Retorna `None` si la cadena no coincide con el patrón; (...)

La misma [documentación](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/re.html#match-objects) dice en cuanto a los *objetos match* u *objetos de coincidencia*:

> Los objetos de coincidencia siempre tienen un valor booleano de `True` («Verdadero»). Ya que `match()` y `search()` retornan `None` cuando no hay coincidencia.

En base al ejemplo de la pregunta, si se imprime nada más `result`, se obtiene lo siguiente:

```py
print(result)   # <re.Match object; span=(0, 15), match='Texto de prueba'>
```

Si se revisan los métodos que admiten los objetos de coincidencia, uno de ellos es `group`. La [documentación](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/re.html#re.Match.group) explica (de nuevo, énfasis mío):

> `Match.group([group1, ...])`
> Retorna uno o más subgrupos de la coincidencia. Si hay un solo argumento, el resultado es una sola cadena; si hay múltiples argumentos, el resultado es una tupla con un elemento por argumento. Sin argumentos, *group1* tiene un valor por defecto de cero (se retorna la coincidencia completa). **Si un argumento *groupN* es cero, el valor de retorno correspondiente es toda la cadena coincidente; si está en el rango inclusivo [1..99], es la cadena coincidente con el grupo correspondiente entre paréntesis.** (...)

Tal énfasis es para mostrar lo que imprime `.group()` en comparativa a lo que se imprime utilizando los corchetes (el ejemplo presente en la pregunta):

```py
result = re.match("Texto de (p.*)", "Texto de prueba")

print(result.group(0))  # Texto de prueba
print(result.group(1))  # prueba

print(result[0])  # Texto de prueba
print(result[1])  # prueba

# ¡es lo mismo!
```

Ahora sí:

##### ¿Qué método podría ser el equivalente (en este caso) en Go?

En el ejemplo de la pregunta, se está utilizando `FindString`. La [documentación de Go](https://pkg.go.dev/regexp#Regexp.FindString) dice:

> `func (re *Regexp) FindString(s string) string`
> `FindString` devuelve una cadena que contiene el texto de la coincidencia más a la izquierda en *s* de la expresión regular. Si no hay ninguna coincidencia, el valor devuelto es una cadena vacía, pero también estará vacía si la expresión regular coincide con éxito con una cadena vacía. **Utilice `FindStringIndex` o `FindStringSubmatch` si es necesario distinguir estos casos**.

La última oración es fundamental aquí. Considerando que los nombres de los métodos son descriptivos, uno puede decantarse por `FindStringSubmatch`. La [documentación](https://pkg.go.dev/regexp#Regexp.FindStringSubmatch) describe:

> `func (re *Regexp) FindStringSubmatch(s string) []string`
> `FindStringSubmatch` devuelve una porción de cadenas que contiene el texto de la coincidencia más a la izquierda de la expresión regular en s y las coincidencias, si las hay, de sus subexpresiones (...) Un valor de retorno `nil` indica que no hay coincidencias.

**Téngase en cuenta que, lo que es un *grupo* en Python, es una *subexpresión* en Go.**

Por lo tanto, haciendo la prueba en Go:

```golang
submatch := re.FindStringSubmatch("Texto de prueba")
fmt.Println(submatch[0])  //Texto de prueba
fmt.Println(submatch[1])  //prueba
    
// ¡es el mismo resultado!
```

¿Por qué hacer la aclaración de que *podría ser* el equivalente? Porque hay diferencias entre `match` y `search` en Python. Un ejemplo rápido:

En Python:

```py
import re

patron = '([bc])([6-8]+)'
cadena = 'a677 b888c867'

result = re.match(patron, cadena)
print(result) # imprime None: la coincidencia no se dio al principio de la cadena

result = re.search(patron, cadena)
print(result) # imprime <re.Match object; span=(5, 9), match='b888'>: la coincidencia se dio en cualquier parte de la cadena

for posicion in range(0,len(result.groups()) +1):
  print(result.group(posicion))

"""
imprime:
b888    (la coincidencia completa)
b       (grupo 1)
888     (grupo 2)
"""
```

En Go:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {

    patron := "([bc])([6-8]+)"
    cadena := "a677 b888c867"

    ren := regexp.MustCompile(patron)
    resu := ren.FindStringSubmatch(cadena)
    fmt.Println(resu) //Imprime [b888 b 888], lo cual es un resultado similar al .search() de Python

    //otra forma de imprimir
    for _, valor := range resu {
        fmt.Println(valor)
        /*imprime:
          b888    (la coincidencia completa)
          b       (grupo 1)
          888     (grupo 2)
        */
    }
}
```